# Makefile rule using variable name

Tags: makefile, rules

I'm trying to write a `makefile` to build a `release` or `debug` version of my program using the same `makefile` (the version selection will be based on env. variable).

My first try was the following:

```
PROG  := myProgram

ifdef DEBUG
BUILD := debug
else
BUILD := release
endif

BIN := $(BUILD)/$(PROG)

SRC := main.c

OBJDIR := $(BUILD)/obj/
OBJ    := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(SRC:%.c=%.o))


$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(GCC) $(OBJ) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

all: $(BIN)
```

When I try to `make` my project, I got the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `release/obj/main.o', needed by `release/myProgram'.  Stop.
```

When I replaced the rule `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` by `$(BUILD)/obj/%.o`, `make` is able to match the rule and build my objects file.

I am confused: why the first rule is not working? 
My understanding is `make` will expand variables in rules before execution, so, in the end, both rules will looks the same?

What is the best practice in this case?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put in an extra slash:

```
OBJDIR := $(BUILD)/obj/


$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    ...
```

The rule, as written, will match the target `release/obj//main.o`, but there is no rule that matches `release/obj/main.o`.

Just remove the offending slash:

```
OBJDIR := $(BUILD)/obj
```

Comment: for information, we need to modify this line `OBJ := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(SRC:%.c=%.o))` to `OBJ := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRC:%.c=%.o))`